# ImageField Form doesn't work in django

Tags: python, django, forms

I know that there's a lot of similar questions to mine on stackoverflow but none of them fixed my problem.

I have a form with an imagefield which doesn't work as it should redirect to the index page when it succeeds but it doesn't. I can create a payment with that image from the admin panel but the form doesn't work.

**models.py**

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Payment_ID = models.ImageField(upload_to='payproof')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="X")
    Review_result = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Not yet reviewed")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s'% self.Status

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Status
```

**views.py**

```
def new_payment(request):
    template ='payment.html'
    form = PayForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index')

    else:
        form = PayForm()

    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Payment_ID = forms.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Payment
        fields = ['Address',
         'Payment_ID']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was simple i was doing `request.POST` but the img is a file so all what i should of done was add `request.FILES`

```
form = PayForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
```